# Handling special characters in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, du

I'm not familiar with bash scripting. Maybe this is a silly question. But I couldn't find the answer. I'm working on a bash script that mimics the behavior of the command `ls -sh` but that actually uses `du -sh` to get file and folder sizes. And it sorts the output. pretty much like `du -sh* | sort -h` with colors.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ "$#" = "0" ]
then
    du -sh *|awk -f /path/to/color-ls.awk|sort -h
else
    du -sh $@|awk -f /path/to/color-ls.awk|sort -h
fi
```

where [ls-color.awk](https://gist.github.com/medanisjbara/7a80597e27ccc8a53448af065a2591d7) is:

```
# color-ls.awk
size=$1;
name=$2;
for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
{
    tmp=(name " " $i);
    name=tmp
}
# filename=($0 ~ /'/)? ("\"" name "\""):("'" name "'")
filename=("'" name "'")
printf $1 " "
cmd=("ls -d " filename " --color")
system(cmd)
```

an awk script that uses `ls --color` to color the output of du -sh

My scripts works fine with most file names even ones containing spaces. but it has some problems involving special characters that I didn't know how to fix.

##### 1. When run without arguments:

It is interpreting any file name that contains single quotes causing an error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

##### 2. When run with arguments:

The same problem as without arguments. And it's interpreting a file name with spaces as two names.

example: when used on a folder named `VirtualBox VMs` or when given `*` as an argument in my home directory here's it's output:

```
du: cannot access 'VirtualBox': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'VMs': No such file or directory
```

##### 3. What I want:

I want the script to skip special characters and pass them as they are to `du`

##### 4. What I tried:

I tried adding double quotes before and after each file name

```sh
parse(){
    for arg in $@
    do
        printf "\"$arg\"\n"
    done
}
```

but it didn't seem to work. du doesn't accept quotes appended to the file name.

```
du: cannot access '"VirtualBox': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'VMs"': No such file or directory
```

Also, replacing quotes with `\'` doesn't help ether. maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

```
# du -sh $(printf "file'name\n" |sed "s/'/\\\'/g")
du: cannot access 'file\'\''name': No such file or directory
# ls file\'name 
"file'name"
```

Same goes for spaces

```
du: cannot access 'VirtualBox\': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'VMs': No such file or directory
```

##### 5. Extra:

I'm trying to make the script works as normal `ls -sh` would work but with sorted output and with more accurate results when it comes to folders. but this script works like `ls -sh -d` when arguments are supplied to it. making `lh Desktop` shows the size of Desktop instead of the size of the individual files and folders inside Desktop. I believe this can be fixed with a loop that checks if each argument is a file or a folder and execute `du -sh` accordingly then sort.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ "$#" = "0" ]
then
    du -sh *|awk -f /path/to/color-ls.awk|sort -h
else
    for i in $@
    do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
            du -sh $i/* |awk -f /path/to/color-ls.awk
        else
            du -sh "$i" |awk -f /path/to/color-ls.awk
        fi
    done|sort -h
fi
```

I'm hoping to find the optimal way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add quotes: `"$@"`

Comment: @Barmar I just did and there was no difference in the output unfortunately

Comment: There is too much in this question, I do not know what to address. `1. When run without arguments: .. t is interpreting any file name that contains single quotes` Your shell script is fine - the problem is that awk is bogus and awk script needs to be fixed. `When run with arguments:` yes, you have to `"$@"`, as above. `What I want:` with `"$@"` you'll be doing that part right.

Comment: The first step in debugging a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so you see all the commands as they're being executed.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by following the answer below and totally abandoning the usage of awk. I will try to fix it and post an update. If I couldn't, I'm probably going to post an independent question about it. The commented line was a condition that uses `'` for filenames that doesn't contain `'` and `"` for filenames that does. But for some reason I couldn't find any difference when using it.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not post so much in one question. Please one problem per question. One script per question, etc.

Make sure to **check your scripts with shellcheck**. It will catch your mistakes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes .

> 1. When run without arguments:

`filename=("'" name "'")` inside awk script is a invalid way to pass anything with `'` quotes to `system()` call, so you are getting unterminated `'` error, as expected, because there will be 3 `'` characters. Fix the AWS script, or better rewrite it in Bash, no need for awk. Maybe rewrite it all in Python or Perl.

Moreover, `tmp=(name " " $i);` deletes tabs and multiple spaces from filenames. It's all meant to work with only nice filenames.

The script will break on newlines in filenames anyway.

> 2. When run with arguments:

`$@` undergoes *word splitting* and *filename expansion* (topics you should research). Word splitting splits the input into words on spaces. Use `"$@"`. Quote the expansions.

> 3. What I want:

You'll be doing that with `"$@"`

> 4. What I tried:

The variable content *is irrelevant*. You have to change the way you *use* the variable, not it's content. I.e. use quotes around the *use* of the variable. Not the content.

> 5. Extra:

You did not quote the expansion. Use `"$i"` not `$i`. It's `"$i"/*`. `$1` undergoes word splitting.

---

And finally, after that all, your script may look like, with GNU tools:

```
if (($# == 0)); then
   set -- *
fi
du -hs0 "$@" |
sort -zh |
sed -z 's/\t/\x00/' |
while IFS= read -r -d '' size && IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   printf "%s " "$size";
   ls -d "$file"
done
```

Also see [How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .

Also, you can chain any statements:

```
if stuff; then
   stuff1
else
   stuff2
fi | 
sort -h |
awk -f yourscriptrt
```

And also don't repeat yourself - use bash arrays:

```
args=()
if stuff; then
  args=(*)
else
  args=("$@")
fi
du -hs "${args[@]}" | stuff...
```

And so that `sort` has less work to do, I would put it right after `du`, not after parsing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll update my post and try fixing it. And I'll take all of what you said into consideration. It seems like I still have a lot to learn.
I tried writing it entirely in bash but I couldn't. python seems like a good idea but I went with bash and awk for the speed advantage and to get some experience on how to use them in a real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't include `shopt -s nullglob`, it's likely that `Desktop/*` didn't expand to any file which is odd unless there really are no files there, you have enabled `nullglob` in interactive mode, and `du -sh` doesn't actually display the sizes of the files in `Desktop`.

It's also likely that you're calling the script from where `Desktop/` doesn't exist.

You can add a debug statement which prints `$PWD`.  You can also try running the script with `bash -x`.

In your script I suggest enabling `nullglob` and then modifying it so `du -sh` isn't called if target directory contains no files.

Something like:

```
set -- "$i"/*; [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && du -sh -- "$@" ...
```

Also `$@` should be quoted when being expanded.

```
for i in "$@"; do
```

This can be simplified to `for i; do`, but we will modify the positional parameters inside the loop so we expand `"$@"` instead.

You can also choose to store the expanded files inside an array as well.

Comment: I will fix the quotes. And you're right, the Desktop folder was actually empty, I can't believe that I made such a mistake. I'm going to update the post. I have no idea what the `shopt -s nullglob` is , so I think I'll do some research on it and post an update.

Comment: @medanisjbara Ok but I suggest you try to make your questions specific and don't update the original question if it becomes a totally different one. Instead create a new one.